# Cannot connect Access with Python

Tags: python, ms-access, connection, driver

I want to connect Access with Python by pypyodbc, but there is an error. The interesting thing that at home it works while on another computer doesn't. I create a new connection link for this computer by File DSN (Microsoft Access Driver) - `'DRIVER={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/PITL;DBQ=C:/PITL/PITL.mdb;'` but nothing.

```
from tkinter import *
import pypyodbc
import ctypes

#Create connection
con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/PITL;DBQ=C:/PITL/PITL.mdb;')
cursor = con.cursor ()

form = Tk ()
form.title ("Main")
form.geometry ('400x400')

def Add ():
    cursor.execute ("SELECT `Law_ID`, `Law_name`, `Fine` FROM Laws WHERE Fine = '2'")
    for row in cursor:
        print (row)

Button=Button(form, text = 'PUSH ME', command = Add)
Button.pack ()

form.mainloop ()

con.commit ()
cursor.close ()
con.close ()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PITL\SHOW DATA.py", line
>   6, in 
>       con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS
>   Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/PITL;DBQ=C:/PITL/PITL.mdb;')   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 2454, in **init**
>       self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 2507, in connect
>       check_success(self, ret)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 1009, in check_success
>       ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py",
>   line 985, in ctrl_err
>       raise Error(state,err_text) pypyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не
>   указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию')

Comment: `Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию` Register your service/driver and does the database exist?

Comment: @dsgdfg The database exist, but how I can register my service/driver?

Comment: [Check this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257231/install-pyodbc-module-for-arcgis-10-5) Script and db in same folder but doesn't  matter, driver work with `environmental path`. Another issue `you can't a module as system wide shared library`(test your db on `powershell` before using with others)